# Problem with React Router and nested routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

This is what I have in my App.js:

```
<Route path='blog/post/:postId' element={<BlogPost/>}></Route> shows a specific post
<Route path='blog' element={<Blog/>}></Route> shows all the posts
<Route path='dashboard' element={<DashBoard/>}></Route>
```

1. If I go to domain/dashboard (through menu) everything works fine.
2. Then I go to domain/blog (through menu) I can see the posts list.
3. Then I go to domain/blog/post/1 (clicking on a previous blog list item) I see the post correctly.
4. But, if now, for example I click on the menu>dashboard, the resulting URL is domain/blog/post/dashboard instead of just domain/dashboard.

I guess I'm missing something about order/priority, but I tried several links I found online and none of them seem to be working for me. Can anyone point me to a solution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The main problem occurs when you are performing onclick function to redirect to a particular screen. Instead of that use the below code for navigation between screens.

In the Latest Version of React Router Dom `history.push` will not work.

Try Using `Link Tag or navigate`

Import this 
`import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";`

`navigate('/your-url')` or `<Link to={'/your-url'} />`